# AVAudioPlayer - Displaying a countdown timer on a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, nstimer

I have a countdown timer that displays the number of seconds left on a audio track. For some reason the countdown is not counting at 1 second intervals, but 2 seconds on the first count and then 1 second on the next count. (It's counting in this pattern - it jumps 2 seconds, then 1 over and over).

here's my code:

```
// display current time left on the track
- (void)updateTimeLeft {
    NSTimeInterval timeLeft = self.player.duration - self.player.currentTime;

    // update your UI with timeLeft
    self.timeDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", timeLeft / 60];

}
```

and here's my NSTimer:

```
NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimeLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
 - (void)updateTimeLeft
{
NSTimeInterval timeLeft = self.player.duration - self.player.currentTime;

int min=timeLeft/60;

int sec = lroundf(timeLeft) % 60;

// update your UI with timeLeft
self. timeDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes %d seconds", min,sec];
}
```

just an idea

Comment: thanks. I'm getting a Invalid operand to binary on the modulus %. I read that the % operator doesn't work on floating-point values.

Comment: concept is divide by 60 for minutes and modulo by 60 for seconds

Comment: this is what I ended up using for the modulus operation.  int sec = lroundf(timeLeft) % 60;

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)updateTimeLeft
 {
NSTimeInterval timeLeft = self.player.duration - self.player.currentTime;

// update your UI with timeLeft
self. timeDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f seconds left", timeLeft];
}
```

try like this...it will display only in seconds

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried that code before. It displays the time in a format that looks like 300.0000 seconds. I need it like 5:30 (5min 30seconds) format.

Answer (score 0):

Best way using system formate:

```
    - (NSString*)updateTimeLeft
    {
        float current = CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentItem.currentTime);
        float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentItem.duration);

        if(!isnan(current) && !isnan(duration)){
             NSTimeInterval timeLeft = duration - current;    
             NSTimeInterval durationInSeconds = timeLeft;
             NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
             formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
             formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;
             NSString *string = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:durationInSeconds];

             return string;
         }

     return nil;
    }
```